# EJS if conditional doesnt work

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I am currently trying to use ejs template in my express application. As indicated in the offical page of the template (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) I am using if conditional to output variable if it has been defined . Like this

```
  <% if (msg) { %>
  <h2><%=msg %></h2>
  <% } else {%>
  <h2>There is no messages</h2>
  <% } %>
```

Unfortunately, everytime I do this server returns 500 error . How do I resolve this?

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with your server, and not with your view. Check how you are sending this data and rendering the view.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `if (msg)` - that's the bit that errors.

Instead, check for existence some other way - by using `typeof` for instance:

```
<% if (typeof msg != "undefined") { %>
<h2><%=msg %></h2>
<% } else {%>
<h2>There is no messages</h2>
<% } %>'
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with strict mode, if variable is not defined, and you reference it, it will throw a `ReferenceError`. If you don't like the `typeof` verbosity, you can pass `undefined` or `null` to your template.